# Why is bread dough recovery important?

Tags: bread, dough, yeast

Im trying to learn all about bread making as im currently doing my svq as a craft baker. One question im having trouble answering is about dought recovory and why it is important. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by recovery?

Comment: Its a question on the svq paper im currently working on. It asks about the importance of dough recovery in relation to retarding and proving. I thought it may be to do with the dough recovering from being in retard, but i really wasnt sure. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you mean, terminology is non-standard.

I'm going to guess you mean what the rest of us call resting or relaxing the dough when working/forming it.

If you overwork dough, the gluten strands that hold it together will tear and break. If you stretch and work the dough until it's springing back, but has not torn, and then let it rest for 5-10 minutes, the gluten strands rearrange themselves such that you can stretch or work the dough further, without it tearing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and taking the time to explain it to me. Im sorry i wasnt very clear in my question. Your awesome.